# Botão True ou False no Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

Gostaria de criar um botão no Angular que ao clicar nele gerasse um valor verdadeiro ou falso no Firebase, como poderia fazer isso? Tenho que criar um botão que grava um valor verdadeiro ou falso no banco de dados, para que meu arduino possa ler este campo no banco de dados e ver se é verdadeiro ou falso para ativar um motor, como posso estar fazendo isso no Angular com Firebase?

Eu já estou fazendo a referência no método

```
statusBotao():void{
  this.referenciaTabelaEsp.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => changes.map(c => ({key: c.payload, ... c.payload.val()}))))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.button = data;
      console.log(this.button);
      //this.banco.list("botoes").update(this.botaoeditar.key, {botao:this.valor.botao})
      

})
```

Provavelmente irei precisar de uma variavel que irá entrar dentro do IF. Por exemplo

```
If (nomedocampo = "true"){
  MUDAR PARA FALSE
  titulodobotao = "O botão está pressionado"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu componente

```
export class MyComponent  {

  itemPath = 'botoes/1';
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Botao>;
  item$: Observable<Botao | undefined>;

  constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc(this.itemPath);
    this.item$ = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }

  update() {
    firebase.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      const ref = this.itemDoc.ref;
      const doc = await transaction.get(ref);
      if (!doc.exists) {
        throw 'documento nao existe!';
      }
      const state = doc.data()!.state;
      transaction.update(ref, { state: !state });
    });
  }
}

export interface Botao {
  state: boolean;
}
```

Template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="item$ | async as btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="update()">{{ btn.state ? 'Ligado' : 'Desligado' }}</button>
</ng-container>
```

lembrar que o botão só aparecerá se o documento 'botao/1' estiver criado no firestore.